# Multiple Instances to distinct WCF-Service from one physical Machine

Tags: c#, wcf

I am running a WCF Service on IIS. Clients connect via net.tcp. Everything works well until one physical machine opens two instances of the client application. Only the second application is then served from the service.

I assume it is a port issue with one machine opening a connection to srvAddress:port/service.svc and the server not knowing to which instance of the client it has to respond.

My first question: If I open ip:port/service.svc on client1 (pc1) what local client port will WCF use to respond? If I then open ip:port/service.svc on client2 (still pc1) why doesn't WCF handle that correctly?

**Server:**

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class WCFService : IWCFService
{
    public State OpenSession(string clientKey)
    {
        Callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IWCFServiceCallback>();            
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
var callback = new WCFServiceCallback();
var instanceContext = new InstanceContext(callback);
Server = new WCFServiceClient(instanceContext);
Server.OpenSession("secret");
```

**WCF Configuration Server**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <!-- Add the following element to your service behavior configuration. -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <!--Hosting in a IIS: -->
      <service name="WCFServiceLibrary.Service.WCFService">
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://myservice.com:808/Service.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InsecureTcp" contract="WCFServiceLibrary.Contract.IWCFService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://myservice.com/Service/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="InsecureTcp" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None" />
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**WCF Configuration Client**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IWCFService">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://myservice.com/Service.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IWCFService" contract="ServiceReference.IWCFService" name="NetTcpBinding_IWCFService"/>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <userSettings />

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/>
  </startup>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Something looks funny with your WCF Client Configuration. It doesn't surprise me that it only serves one service. Can we see the entire configuration file?

Comment: hi @Aelphaeis I have updated the configuration as you requested :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure whats wrong; however, I suspect that these steps will help you to debug it.

Your WCF should have the Output type of a Class Library. Create another project in the same solution and add your WCF service as a reference to your new project.

Next, open your WCF Service manually from the Console. You can do that with code that looks similar to the following.

```
        //Alternatively you can use :
        //ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ApiTestService), new Uri(PipeService));
        Api api = new ApiTestService();
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(api,new Uri(PipeService));

        //Add all your bindings.
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IApiService), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), ApiPipeServiceName);

        host.BeginOpen(OnOpen, host);
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.BeginClose(OnClose, host);
```

where OnOpen and OnClose look like below.

```
    void OnOpen(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        ServiceHost service = (ServiceHost)ar.AsyncState;
        service.EndOpen(ar);
    }
    void OnClose(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        ServiceHost service = (ServiceHost)ar.AsyncState;
        service.EndClose(ar);
    }
```

Then attempt to import the service reference again and compare your configuration files. If you notice that both requests are being service it means something is probably wrong with the configuration of your WCF. If you still find that you're unable to service your second request it probably means that you should attempt to manually access your service:

You can do so using by creating a proxy for your service.

This would be an example of a Proxy Class :

```
public class MyPipeClient : IMyService, IDisposable
{   
    //Sub IMyService with your service interface contract
    ChannelFactory<IMyService> myServiceFactory;

    public MyPipeClient()
    {
        // Sub NetNamedPipeBinding with your bindings.
        myServiceFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress(Constants.myPipeService + @"/" + Constants.myPipeServiceName) );


    }

    //Implementation Details no one cares about would go here
    //...
    //Example where Hello is one of the functions from my Service.
    public String Hello(String Name)
    {
        return Channel.Hello(Name);
    }


    public IMyService Channel
    {
        get
        {
            return myServiceFactory.CreateChannel();
        }
    }
}
```

This should point you very close to whatever the problem is.